# Insert into Table from #tempTable fails

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

I am simply taking the data from a Table and insert it into #tempTable then delete the data, and insert it back to the table. I get "Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." Error.

Here are the lines I am running.

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM dbo.ProductSales 

SELECT * FROM #tempTable

DELETE FROM dbo.ProductSales

INSERT INTO dbo.ProductSales SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Does ProductSales have any computed columns?

Answer (score 6):

If `ProductSales` has an identity or timestamp/rowversion column you will not be able to use `SELECT *` to do an insert. Instead, enumerate the columns skipping the identity column:

```
Insert ProductSales(Col1, Col2....
Select Col1, Col2...
From #tempTable
```